# Plotting text on basemap

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap, annotate

Suppose I want to plot 'text' on a basemap over Spain, this would work.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


m = Basemap(resolution='l')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
plt.annotate('Text',xy=(0,40),ha="center")
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work on Merc view, no matter what x/y value I specify. E.g:

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc',resolution='c',llcrnrlat=36,llcrnrlon=-20,urcrnrlat=61,urcrnrlon=33)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
plt.annotate('Text',xy=(0,40),ha="center")
plt.show()
```

Will only show the text in the very bottom left. How to plot text in this view?

Comment: Okay, plt.annotate('Text',xy=(2000000,4000000),ha="center") works so it seems to be using meters from some point. How do I use degree co-ordinates?

Comment: SOLVED: xpt,ypt = m(x,y) (convert degree to m coordinates)